# Accessing SAMBA shares (Ubuntu server) over PPTP

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, samba, pptp

I have a VPS set up as a storage server and a seedbox, running SAMBA and a PPTP VPN server, running Ubuntu server LTS 16.04. My goal is to be able to mount the shares add a network drive on my windows 10 computer, through the VPN. However, I can't access the shares, even though I can ping the server from my PC and access the other services running (SSH works, as well as Deluged for example), but the server doesn't show up in Network in the file explorer.

The virtual adapter on Windows is set up to perform split tunnelling, but I don't think that's where the problem is coming from. The basic configuration of Samba seems to be fine too, since I can access the share using AndSMB on Android while my phone is connected to the VPN. This leads me to think that the problem has to do with the network discovery mechanism of Windows, but I'm not sure how to fix this issue since I'm not very familiar with NetBIOS and WINS. I've tried enabling "WINS Support" in the Samba config file, but it doesn't seem to help by itself.

Should I just give up on PPTP and switch to a more reliable VPN technology (L2TP or IPSec)? I'm using PPTP for the low CPU usage and ease of installation, and I don't particularly care about security since I'm using the server to store publicly available files only as far as unencrypted data goes.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your VPN technology is irrelevant if you've successfully connected to the VPN server. Can you access the network shares using the VPN server IP address (not its public IP)?

Comment: Nope, at least not using the Windows file manager as the client (\\172.16.0.1\myShare), but like I said, it works using a SMB client on Android while connected to the VPN from my phone.

Comment: What Samba version are you using?

Comment: From _apt-cache policy samba_ : `samba:
  Installed: 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.7`

Comment: Upgrade your Samba to the latest version (4 at least) as Windows 10 is defaulting to the SMB3 protocol and not SMB1 that your current Samba is using - hence why it can't see the shares it is exposing. Additionally, with the latest cyber attacks with WannaCry ransomware you should be doing everything you can to move to SMB3 as your default protocol...

Comment: It is already the case, since this is version 4.3.11, which is apparently the latest version available for Ubuntu server.

Comment: Sorrrrry, I read it wrong! Can you post up your `smb.conf`. i wonder if there is a line `smb ports = 139` - try commenting this line out and reload the conf and restart Samba.

Comment: No worries :) This is the current config file (like I mentioned in the Pastebin, `ppp0` is the name of the virtual PPTP interface) : https://pastebin.com/N8hPjcRm

Comment: Ah, I think it might be related to Samba not being able to reliably bind to your PPP interface. Try changing your interface to the PPP interface IP address. What you're trying to do and the problem experienced makes sense... Samba (upon starting) will try to bind to your interface - but only if it is UP - your PPP interface won't be up unless you have connected to it but you need to connect to it before starting Samba so that Samba sees it as "UP". As a test - to keep your smb.conf as it is - connect to your VPN -> restart the Samba services -> try and connect to the share.

Comment: Changing from the interface name to the IP did the trick! I had no idea PPTP acted like this (I've only worked with L2TP before). It's quite strange that Windows still can't detect the share automatically though, but now I can access it directly by IP. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's nothing to do with Windows, it's everything to do with Samba ignoring an interface that's DOWN :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice from Big Chris in the comments, it appears that the issue was that Samba was unable to bind to the virtual interface `ppp0` in my `smb.conf`, because the PPTP interface was down as it was not connected to my client. I managed to fix the problem by replacing the `interfaces = ppp0` line with `interfaces = 172.16.0.1`, which is the private IP of my server.

With this modification, I am able to access the share by IP address from my Windows 10 client (`\\172.16.0.1\myShare`).